# Plaidml wont setup: 'plaidml-setup' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, plaidml

I am on a windows machine, and I am attempting to set up plaidml after installing using the "**plaidml-setup**" command, but it does not work. I keep getting the "**'plaidml-setup' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**" error. I have already installed plaidml using the "**pip install -U plaidml-keras**" command, and have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it.

I've searched online to solve the issue but cannot find why the command will not work and allow me to chose my AMD gpu. The only information I was able to find were people repeating the "**pip install -U plaidml-keras**" and "**plaidml-setup**" commands.

Answer (score 0):

The console doesn't recognize the command, because you are trying to call a program which does not exist in the location you are in. You are either in the wrong location (go to the correct one by typing cd [path]) or call the program with the correct name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you computer is configured like mine, you want to navigate to `C:\Python38\Lib\site-packages\plaidml`

and run `./plaidml_setup.py`  or perhaps using `python plaidml_setup.py` if the former doesn't work for you

source: [see this response to a similar ticket](https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/issues/1731#issuecomment-806576459)